# Re-creating touch-based gestures with Playwright to test mobile viewports

Tags: android, ios, automated-tests, playwright

Can someone help me re-create touch-based gestures(swipe, zoom, pinch, etc.) in Playwright to test emulated mobile devices? It has only a tap method out of the box, which works perfectly, but I need a whole set of functionality to test the mobile viewports of our web application.

I have tried so far a couple of scripts that I found online, which are not failing my tests but rather don't work for me for some reason:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const target = document.querySelector("#abc");
  target.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
      console.log('touch start');
  });
  
  function simulateTouchEvent(element, type, touches) {
    const touchEvents = [];
  
    touches.forEach((touch) => {
      touchEvents.push(new Touch({
        clientX: touch.x,
        clientY: touch.y,
        identifier: touch.id,
        target: element,
      }));
    });
  
    element.dispatchEvent(new TouchEvent(type, {
      touches: touchEvents,
      view: window,
      cancelable: true,
      bubbles: true,
    }));
  }
  
  simulateTouchEvent(target, 'touchstart', [{
    id: "123",
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
  }]);

 simulateTouchEvent(target, 'touchend', [{
    id: "123",
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
  }]);
})
```

also this

```
const el = await page.locator(
                ".selector"
            );
const dataTransfer = await page.evaluateHandle(
                () => new DataTransfer()
            );

await el.dispatchEvent("touchstart", { dataTransfer, steps: 5 });
await el.dispatchEvent("touchend", { dataTransfer, steps: 5 });
```

and

```
async function dispatchTouchEvent(
  playWright: Page,
  type: 'touchstart' | 'touchend' | 'touchcancel' | 'touchmove',
  selector: string,
  page?: Position,
  screen?: Position,
  client?: Position,
  options?: PageExtraTouchOptions,
) {
  await playWright.$eval(
    selector,
    (el, options) => {
      const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

      const {
        client = {},
        page = {},
        screen = {},
        type,
        options: touchOpt,
      } = options;

      const touchObj = new Touch({
        clientX: client.x,
        clientY: client.y,
        identifier: Date.now(),
        pageX:
          page.x || (client.x !== undefined ? rect.left + client.x : undefined),
        pageY:
          page.y || (client.y !== undefined ? rect.top + client.y : undefined),
        screenX: screen.x,
        screenY: screen.y,
        target: el,
      });

      const touchEvent = new TouchEvent(type, {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        ...touchOpt,
        changedTouches: [touchObj],
        targetTouches: [touchObj],
        touches: [touchObj],
      });
      return el.dispatchEvent(touchEvent);
    },
    { client, options, page, screen, type },
  );
}

await dispatchTouchEvent(
                page,
                "touchstart",
                ".selector"
            );
await dispatchTouchEvent(
                page,
                "touchend",
                ".selector"
            );
```

I recently have been also looking into [Playwrights experimental android](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-android) emulation feature, in the hopes that it might help me to emulate at least an android device, but haven't even been able to even run it because of ECONNREFUSED error.

Would appreciate any help, because I`m completely stuck in here.

Playwright version: 1.23;
OS: Ubuntu Neon KDE 20.04;

Comment: have you managed to get it work?

Comment: No. Tried all of the solutions that I found online, but none of them worked for our web app. Have seen people in Playwright slack working on their own solutions for this issue, with the use of their own testing frameworks, based on Playwright, but its not an option for me.

Comment: Currently waiting for BrowserStack to implement experimental Android testing with PW remotely on real devices, which has native support for all of the gestures. It will cover at least Android devices for our testing needs.